# Hi, I deleted my .../hadoop/tmp directory ... will I have to compile hadoop again?

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2

I deleted my .../hadoop/tmp directory ... will I have to compile hadoop again ?

How do I fix it, I thought it just I made it again but I do not know what other files and folders it contained

Answer (score 0):

Is this a directory in local file system or HDFS? In either case, you can issue mkdir to create this directory and assign appropriate permissions

Comment: I got it corrected, Thanks, why is the question down voted? I am new to stack overflow